# Cordova Getting values from form using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, dom

Trying to get values from form using addEventListener.

Following is my code:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.write("<form id='submit_search' action='' method='GET'><input type='text' name='field[s]' placeholder='search'><button type='submit'>Search</button></form>")
    document.getElementById('submit_search').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault;
        process_search(this);
    }, false);   
},

function process_search(element){
    var search=element.querySelector("input[name='field[s]']").val();
    alert("You searched for"+search);
}
```

The alert box does not display. Wonder if the preventDefault is working.

Comment: any console errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Javascript you get the input value using `.value` instead of `val()`.
In your code, the execution stops and you cannot see the alert, i am sure you got console errors:

`var search= element.querySelector("input[name='field[s]']").value;`